# Copying elements to a new namespace with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I am trying to change the namespace of my XML file. I'm close but getting a slight issue with the root element.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cd="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachine" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachine.DataContracts" exclude-result-prefixes="cd">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <!-- Identify transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- Create a new element in the new namespace for all elements -->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Inventory xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachine" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Schema>2018</Schema>
  <Machines>
    <Machine>
      <Price>120000</Price>
      <Properties i:nil="true" />
    </Machine>
  </Machines>
</Inventory>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Inventory xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachine.DataContracts">
  <Schema>2018</Schema>
  <Machines>
    <Machine>
      <Price>120000</Price>
      <Properties i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
    </Machine>
  </Machines>
</Inventory>
```

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Inventory xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachine.DataContracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <Schema>2018</Schema>
  <Machines>
    <Machine>
      <Price>120000</Price>
      <Properties i:nil="true" />
    </Machine>
  </Machines>
</Inventory>
```

What tweaks do I need to make the XML input transform correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to put a namespace declaration (here `xmlns:i`) on an element where it isn't actually used (in the name of the element or any of its attributes).

In XSLT 2.0 you can use the xsl:namespace instruction.

```
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:namespace name="i" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

In this particular case, the namespace is present in the source document, so you can copy it across (which also works in XSLT 1.0):

```
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::i"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```